# Map a HasMany relationship without any key column whatsoever - Where() only

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Conceptually I want to map a collection like this:

```
HasMany(x => x.Children).Where("some_column_name='foo'");
```

The default mode of HasMany() requires me to provide a KeyColumn which should exist on the child table, and whose value should be the identifier value of the parent.  But, I don't want to do that. I want to provide the only and entire sql clause for the join to this child table relationship.

Is it possible?

I tried leaving off the KeyColumn from the mapping entirely. But, nHibernate adds something to the generated sql by default -- it seems to be some kind of identifier placeholder for the parent class. For instance if the parent class of this relationship is called "Parent" then nH generates sql like

select .... from children child0_ where ([my custom where clause, yay]) **and child0_.Parent_id=?**

I want it to stop adding any additional clauses to this join and use ONLY my custom where clause provided by the .Where() method of the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact scenario so there might be an easier solution but this should work.

classes used

```
class Parent : Entity
{
    public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; protected set; } = new List<Child>();
}

class Child : Entity
{
    public virtual string ChildType { get; set; }
}
```

mapping

```
class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        HasMany(x => x.Children)
            .PropertyRef(nameof(ChildType))
            .KeyColumn("ChildType")
            .Cascade.All();

        Map(x => ChildType).Access.Using<ChildTypeGetter>().Formula("'foo'");
    }

    public string ChildType { get; set; }
}

class ChildTypeGetter : IPropertyAccessor, IGetter, ISetter
{
    public IGetter GetGetter(Type theClass, string propertyName) => this;
    public ISetter GetSetter(Type theClass, string propertyName) => this;

    public bool CanAccessThroughReflectionOptimizer => false;
    public string PropertyName => nameof(ParentMap.ChildType);
    public Type ReturnType => typeof(string);
    public MethodInfo Method => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public object Get(object target) => "foo";
    public object GetForInsert(object owner, IDictionary mergeMap, ISessionImplementor session) => Get(owner);
    public void Set(object target, object value) { }
}

class ChildMap : ClassMap<Child>
{
    public ChildMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        Map(x => x.ChildType);
    }
}
```

Testcode

```
session.Save(new Child { ChildType = "foo" });
session.Save(new Child { ChildType = "foo" });
session.Save(new Child { ChildType = "bar" });
var parentId = session.Save(new Parent());
session.Flush();
session.Clear();

var parent = session.Get<Parent>(parentId);

Assert.Equal(2, parent.Children.Count);
```

Comment: Super idea to customize a property accessor for a nonexistent property on the parent. I will try this today. Initially I'm wondering whether I even need the IPropertyAccessor, is the Formula mapping maybe enough? I plan to find out.

Thanks for the response!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't quite get me all the way there.  The key goal is to use only the Where() clause in the join and nothing else, I think. After implementing a custom property accessor and everything else here, the resulting query syntax ends up looking like:  
`... from child child0_ where ([clause from Where]) and child0_.EntityType=@p0`

Comment: the where was supposed to be replaced with the fake property. That's why there is no where in the example code at all. If there should be other conditions in the where they should be added to the fake property as well